# POST body values are not recognized

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, post, swift3

I am calling a POST API but the post values are not getting recognised.
I am using alamofire for API handling

```
 public func POSTRequest(postData : AnyObject?,APIName : String?,headers: HTTPHeaders?,success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (String,String) -> Void)
        {
            let url = URL(string: APIName!)!
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        urlRequest.httpBody = postData as? Data
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
        manager.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { ( responseData) -> Void in

            if responseData.result.isSuccess {
                let statusCode = responseData.response?.statusCode
                if(statusCode == 200){
                    let resJson = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                    success(resJson)
                }
                else {
                    let resJson = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                    let errorMsg = resJson["message"].stringValue
                    let errorTitle = resJson["title"].stringValue
                    failure(errorMsg,errorTitle)
                }
            }
            if responseData.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseData.result.error!
                failure(error.localizedDescription,"")
            }
        }
    }



// MARK: Login
    func userLogin(postData: AnyObject, completionHandler:@escaping (JSON) -> Void,failure:@escaping (String,String) -> Void)
    {
        let apiName = GlobalConstants.rootUrl + GlobalConstants.loginUrl

        let httpHeaders: HTTPHeaders = getHeaders()

        ApiRequestHandler.shared.POSTRequest(postData: postData, APIName: apiName, headers: httpHeaders, success: { (JSON) in
            print("JSON \(JSON)")
            completionHandler(JSON)
        })
        { (Errormsg,ErrorTitle) in
            print("Error \(Errormsg)")
            failure(Errormsg,ErrorTitle)
        }
    }
```

I am creating the post data here

```
        let postDataDct = NSMutableDictionary()
        postDataDct.setValue(self.userNameTextField.text, forKey: "username")
        postDataDct.setValue(self.phoneNumberTextField.text, forKey: "mobile")

        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: 
        postDataDct , options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) 
        as NSData else {
            return;
        }
        print(NSString(data: data as Data, encoding: 
        String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String)
```

header creation here

```
func getHeaders() -> HTTPHeaders {
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json" ,"Authorization" : "Basic dGFuaXNocWdfgaFF%waXJvb3Q6dzBEMFlkSnR0"]
    return headers
}
```

I am calling the login method here

```
   ApiManager.shared.userLogin(postData: postDataDct as AnyObject, completionHandler: { (JSON) in
      print(JSON)
    })
    { (ErrorMsg, ErrorTitle) in
        print(ErrorMsg)
    }
```

Please help me to find the issue.

API is giving me error response, saying user name or password is empty.

Comment: can you add the code where you are calling the login method?

Comment: @vijeesh the error says that the user name or password is empty.  the variable postDataDct which has the parameters that you are setting, it is having only the "username" and the "mobile" field and not having the password field.

Comment: Could you please add the total post data function...?

Comment: Don't use Foundation types when they have native Swift equivalents. Use `Dictionary`, `String` and `Data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Posting Alamofire have its own Parameters Class Try to use that like this with make share using the exact keys as on server.

```
let parameter: Parameters = [
        "Email": txtfld_email.text!,
        "Password": txtfld_password.text!    
                              ]
```

Comment: I figured it  that API is supporting only form data.

Answer (score 1):

**Cross check your keys:**

```
let postDataDct = NSMutableDictionary()
postDataDct.setValue(self.userNameTextField.text, forKey: "username")
postDataDct.setValue(self.phoneNumberTextField.text, forKey: "mobile")
```

You are making the request with `username` and `mobile` It seems like the keys will be **`username` and `password`** according to the response you are getting **name or password is empty.**

```
let postDataDct = NSMutableDictionary()
postDataDct.setValue(self.userNameTextField.text, forKey: "username")
postDataDct.setValue(self.phoneNumberTextField.text, forKey: "password")
```

**Suggestion:**

> Don't use NSMutableDictionary in Swift, use its native Swift
>   counterpart, Dictionary

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift, use its native Swift counterpart, `Dictionary`.

Comment: Yes also thanks for reminding, here I am only showing the problem with the associated question!

Comment: Rather than just fixing one of the issues with OP's code, you should always try to fix all issues instead of encouraging OP to continue using code that shouldn't be used by showing the same discouraged methods in your answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right but I want to remember to you that we can give a suggestion because that is not the only code in this project and he uses the same in the whole project due to the habit you can only fix that piece of code but, How do you fix all the code? so better is this to give the suggestion!!!

Comment: Also, If I fix that code according to native Swift counterpart may be it will create the issue for him!